# Neo4j 2.0.0.M05 - Cypher changes in function predicates by labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Today, I tried updating `Neo4j` to `2.0.0.M05`. After running my application's tests, what failed for me is filtering nodes by (multiple) labels.

Before, I tried doing this with (source: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.0-M05/query-where.html#where-filter-on-node-label):

```
START node=node(*) WHERE node LABEL [:mylabel] RETURN node
```

Which fails with error you can see here: http://console-test.neo4j.org/r/irh886

As a workaround, I used function predicates and created query:

```
START node=node(*) 
WHERE ANY (label in labels(node) WHERE label IN ['mylabel'])
RETURN node
```

This worked in `2.0.0.M03` and `2.0.0.M04`, but doesn't work in `2.0.0.M05` with error you can see here: http://console-test.neo4j.org/r/scx0j4

Any breaking change in `2.0.0.M05` I'm missing from changelog? I've been looking at http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/09/neo4j-200m05-released.html, but can't notice any change connected with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that seems like a documentation issue. It looks like they've removed the long `LABEL` predicate form.

It looks like the ways to do that are:

```
WHERE node:myLabel:myLabel2
```

or

```
WHERE node:myLabel OR node:myLabel2
```

If you really need to compare against an array like you're doing, then your workaround seems reasonable. Although using `node(*)` doesn't seem like the best way to efficiently find labeled nodes.

The old parser is still accessible if you prefix your cypher query with `cypher legacy`, but it seems to be removed from there as well in M05.

Comment: Tnx for your answer!
So, if I understand documentation correctly, node:myLabel:myLabel2 means that, node must have both labels, not any of those two.
Furthermore, in M03 my workaround parsed quite faster than your second example (node:myLabel OR node:myLabel2), which is why I used it instead of your second example.
Node(*) is just for an example. In my case, there is always a list of node ids, so I always have e.g. node(1, 2, 3).
In your opinion, is this a bug, that should be reported?

Comment: I mentioned the docs issue to the neo guys, and they're going to fix it. Feel free to report a performance problem with the `OR` query if you think it's significant. (and yes, the first one is an `AND` of the label predicates)

Comment: Well, for a bug, I really meant the function predicate (second example in my question) that doesn't work. For the possible performance problem, I'll look into it and see how it behaves in M05.